# Delphi IdHTTP server load html

Tags: delphi, indy

I have created a VCL application and I need to create an HTTP server that runs in my network. I have created the code that you can see below:

```
procedure TForm1.IdHTTPServer1CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
var
  a: TStringList;
  count, logN: integer;
begin

 if ARequestInfo.Document = '/' then
  begin

   AResponseInfo.ResponseNo := 200;
   AResponseInfo.ContentText := IndexMemo.Lines.Text;
   Memo1.Lines.Add(' Client: ' + ARequestInfo.RemoteIP);

  end
 else
  begin

   AResponseInfo.ResponseNo := 200;
   AResponseInfo.ContentText := '<html><body><b>404 NOT FOUND</b></body></html>';

  end;

end;
```

Now I have only a test case `if ARequestInfo.Document = '/' then` but later I'll need a lot of them. I have found this solution:

1. Drop a memo in the form
2. Add the html inside the memo
3. Load the text of the memo in the `ContextText`

I don't think that this is very efficient because I'd have to drop like 20 TMemo in my form and the HTML will be difficult to maintain. I thought that I could load the html pages with the `Deployment manager`.

[image]

In the same folder of the Delphi project I have created a folder called `pages` and it will contain the html files. I am not sure on how to load html pages with an indy HTTP server, so my questions are:

1. Do I have to store the html pages somewhere in a folder and then load them using indy?
2. Can I load html pages with indy that are included in the Deployment page?

---

**Note**: I would like to have a single exe (which is the http server) and not a folder with exe + html files. The solution that I have found works pretty well because I use a lot of `TMemo` to store the code, but this is not easy to maintain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, the code you have shown is not thread-safe.  `TIdHTTPServer` is a multi-threaded component, the `OnCommand...` events are triggered in the context of worker threads.  You must synchronize with the main UI thread in order to access UI controls safely, eg:

```
procedure TForm1.IdHTTPServer1CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
var
  s: string;
begin
  if ARequestInfo.Document = '/' then
  begin
    TThread.Synchronize(nil,
      procedure
      begin
        s := IndexMemo.Lines.Text;
        Memo1.Lines.Add(' Client: ' + ARequestInfo.RemoteIP);
      end
    );

    AResponseInfo.ResponseNo := 200;
    AResponseInfo.ContentText := s;
    AResponseInfo.ContentType := 'text/plain';
  end
  else
  begin    
    AResponseInfo.ResponseNo := 404;
    AResponseInfo.ContentText := '<html><body><b>404 NOT FOUND</b></body></html>';
    AResponseInfo.ContentType := 'text/html';
  end;
end;
```

> 1. Do I have to store the html pages somewhere in a folder and then load them using indy?
> 2. Can I load html pages with indy that are included in the Deployment page?

If you want to serve files from the local filesystem, you have to translate the `ARequestInfo.Document` property value to a local file path, and then you can either:

1. load the requested file into a `TFileStream` and assign it to the `AResponseInfo.ContentStream` property:

   ```
   procedure TForm1.IdHTTPServer1CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
     ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
   var
     str, filename: string;
   begin
     str := ' Client: ' + ARequestInfo.RemoteIP + ' requesting: ' + ARequestInfo.Document;
     TThread.Queue(nil,
       procedure
       begin
         Memo1.Lines.Add(str);
       end
     );

     if TextStartsWith(ARequestInfo.Document, '/') then
     begin
       filename := Copy(ARequestInfo.Document, 2, MaxInt);
       if filename = '' then
         filename := 'index.txt';

       // determine local path to requested file
       // (ProcessPath() is declared in the IdGlobalProtocols unit)...
       filename := ProcessPath(YourDeploymentFolder, filename);

       if FileExists(filename) then
       begin
         AResponseInfo.ResponseNo := 200;
         AResponseInfo.ContentStream := TFileStream.Create(filename, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
         AResponseInfo.ContentType := IdHTTPServer1.MIMETable.GetFileMIMEType(filename);
         Exit;
       end;
     end;

     AResponseInfo.ResponseNo := 404;
     AResponseInfo.ContentText := '<html><body><b>404 NOT FOUND</b></body></html>';
     AResponseInfo.ContentType := 'text/html';
   end;
   ```
2. pass the file path to the `TIdHTTPResponseInfo.(Smart)ServeFile()` method and let it handle the file for you:

   ```
   procedure TForm1.IdHTTPServer1CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
     ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
   var
     str, filename: string;
   begin
     str := ' Client: ' + ARequestInfo.RemoteIP + ' requesting: ' + ARequestInfo.Document;
     TThread.Queue(nil,
       procedure
       begin
         Memo1.Lines.Add(str);
       end
     );

     if TextStartsWith(ARequestInfo.Document, '/') then
     begin
       filename := Copy(ARequestInfo.Document, 2, MaxInt);
       if filename = '' then
         filename := 'index.txt';

       // determine local path to requested file...
       filename := ProcessPath(YourDeploymentFolder, filename);

       AResponseInfo.SmartServeFile(AContext, ARequestInfo, filename);
       Exit;
     end;

     AResponseInfo.ResponseNo := 404;
     AResponseInfo.ContentText := '<html><body><b>404 NOT FOUND</b></body></html>';
     AResponseInfo.ContentType := 'text/html';
   end;
   ```

> I would like to have a single exe (which is the http server) and not a folder with exe + html files.

In that case, save the HTML files into the EXE's resources at compile-time (using an `.rc` file, or the IDE's [Resources and Images](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Resources_and_Images) dialog. See [Resource Files Support](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Resource_Files_Support) for more details) and then translate the `ARequestInfo.Document` into a resource ID/Name that you can load with `TResourceStream` for use as the `AResponseInfo.ContentStream` object:

```
procedure TForm1.IdHTTPServer1CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
var
  str, resID: string;
  strm: TResourceStream;
begin
  str := ' Client: ' + ARequestInfo.RemoteIP + ' requesting: ' + ARequestInfo.Document;
  TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add(str);
    end
  );

  if TextStartsWith(ARequestInfo.Document, '/') then
  begin
    // determine resource ID for requested file
    // (you have to write this yourself)...
    resID := TranslateIntoResourceID(Copy(ARequestInfo.Document, 2, MaxInt));
    try
      strm := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, resID, RT_RCDATA);
    except
      on E: EResNotFound do
        strm := nil;
    end;

    if strm <> nil then
    begin
      AResponseInfo.ResponseNo := 200;
      AResponseInfo.ContentStream := strm;
      AResponseInfo.ContentType := 'text/html';
      Exit;
    end;
  end;

  AResponseInfo.ResponseNo := 404;
  AResponseInfo.ContentText := '<html><body><b>404 NOT FOUND</b></body></html>';
  AResponseInfo.ContentType := 'text/html';
end;
```

Comment: Always the best, you've solved a big problem here. I didn't think about the fact that it's running on a separate thread. Many thanks

Comment: where does the TranslateIntoResourceID come from? Same thing with TextStartsWith but I have quickly solved using if ARequestInfo.Document.Chars[0] = '/' then

Comment: "*where does the TranslateIntoResourceID come from?*" - you have to write it yourself.  "*Same thing with TextStartsWith*" - in Indy's `IdGlobal` unit.

Answer (score 4):

You can read the Content from a file

```
procedure TForm2.IdHTTPServer1CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext; ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
  var Page : TStringStream;
begin
  Page := TStringStream.Create;
  Page.LoadFromFile('put the file path here');
  AResponseInfo.ResponseNo := 200;
  AResponseInfo.ContentStream := page;
end;
```

You can read the Content from a Resource, go to Project Menu, Resources and Imagens, add the resources that you need.

```
procedure TForm2.IdHTTPServer1CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext; ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo); 
      var page : TResourceStream;
    begin
      //home is the resource name
      page := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, 'home', RT_RCDATA);
      AResponseInfo.ResponseNo := 200;
      AResponseInfo.ContentStream := page;
    end;
```

Comment: `TIdHTTPResponseInfo` has `(Smart)ServeFile()` methods available, you don't need to open and read the files yourself.

Comment: You should use `TFileStream` (or Indy's `TIdReadFileExclusiveStream` or `TIdReadFileNonExclusiveStream`) instead of `TStringStream`. There is no need to load the file into memory at all (and certainly not as a **string**). In both examples, don't forget to set `AResponseInfo.ContentType`, either.